# Center Align View With respect to another view

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-xml

I want to center align my view1 over another view2 , and view2 and view1 both are of custom size.

```
View1
|------------------------|
|                        |
|                        |
|     |---------|        |
|     |   View2 |        |
|     |---------|        |
|                        |
|------------------------|
```

**Note:** View2 is in the middle/center of view1 and view1 is not parent , how can i achieve this?

**My Attempt:**

```
<!-- some xml of another parents -->
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pin"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<!--- long xml --->
```

Comment: What you have tried? Please paste your code

Comment: Added my example , i forgot there you go my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code... itz working for me

Let View1=ImageView;
View2=TextView;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/overlapImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

    android:src="@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTittle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Center Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in this particular case which is view1 and view 2?

Comment: view1 is 50dp by 50dp and view2 is 25dp by 25dp , now this fails if i have more parent above RelativeLayout

Comment: set height and weight for parent Relative layout instead for view1

Comment: i got your point thanks , i solved my problem , after some hit and trial